# using Reduce to solve a system of an equation and an inequality

Tags: equation-solving

```
   Manipulate[Module[{a, b, β, v},
           Reduce[{a/b^2 + 1/a == (2 b)/a^2 + 2/3 β b && (3 v)/(
                 4 π a^2) <b < (3 v)/(2 π a^2)}, b, Reals] // N],
          {β, 50, 200}, {v, 1*10^-9, 10*10^-9}
         ]
```

I was trying to solve the equation in the Reduce function for a, so I get a(b).Then put the result in the inequality in Reduce to get the numerical range of b. Also I wanted to manipulate beta and v to see how the range of b changes accordingly. But my outcome shows some crazy answer with like 10 || (or).

```
{β ((a$9202 < 
      0. && ((β$9202 < (
          0.0625 (-48. + 12. a$9202 + 3. a$9202^3))/a$9202^2 && 
         v$9202 > 0. && 
         b$9202 == 
          Root[-3 a$9202^3 - 
             3 a$9202 #1^2 + (6 + 2 a$9202^2 β$9202) #1^3 &, 
           1]) || ((0.0625 (-48. + 12. a$9202 + 3. a$9202^3))/
          a$9202^2 < β$9202 < -(3./a$9202^2) && v$9202 < 0. && 
         b$9202 == 
          Root[-3 a$9202^3 - 
             3 a$9202 #1^2 + (6 + 2 a$9202^2 β$9202) #1^3 &, 1])||
```

(A part of the outcome I got)

Why doen't it give me one `sth<b<sth` cleanly? beta and v are constants that I can choose with manipulate and the first equality gives me the value of a with respect to b. 
(btw what do those $s and #s mean?)

Comment: Don't use `Module[]` here.

Comment: `((3 v) b)/(4 \[Pi] a^2) < (3 v)/(2 \[Pi] a^2)` reduces to `b < 2 && a != 0` are you sure this is correct?

Comment: Thank you for replying. ohh oops. I missed one < before b. I edited my question.